# iPhone: Restart the app after clicking on a button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My app has a logout button and when the user hits that button, I need to kill all the existing views and background tasks (though I don't want to see the launch image again).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually handle this is to have the LoginViewController be the RootViewController of the app with a NavigationController. On the LoginController I set the NavigationBar to be hidden.

Then it's just a simple.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

And all of your views are gone/killed (if you built them properly) so you'll only have to handle killing off any background processes that are not managed by the views.

Answer (score 0):

In order to kill the views, just change the `rootViewController` property of the `window`.

Something like

```
self.window.rootViewController = //The new view controller to be presented here
```

In order to kill the background tasks it depends on the nature of the tasks. If you have a reference to them, you can kill them manually when logging out.